# Could not resolve dependency: reactjs "npm install" on MacOS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-install

I'm getting this error when I try to "npm install" in a reactjs app i'm trying to get running on my MacBook.   I'm pretty new to working with reactjs and actually haven't coded for a really long time.    But trying to get my feet wet again by setting up a development environment to work on an app that others have been writing so far.

Anyone know what the best way is to resolve this?

I'm hesitant to "force" it because I think that's likely to lead to a bunch of other issues.   Want to go about this correctly.  I have actually got this app running on remote servers running Linux before now and never had this issue.

[image: Screenshot when I try to do "npm install"]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a conflict between the dependency versions in the project. Just run this as suggested in the error log:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

If this doesn't work you'll have to take your chances and use the force flag. You can always go back if things don't work out

```
npm install --force
```

Comment: I'd rather try to remove the conflict than take my chances..   I did try it with --force first and it seemed to create a big mess so i deleted the node_modules..  i don't have this issue on other systems i have done this on so i was hoping to make it go smooth like there..   i'll try the legacy-peer-deps..  see how it goes.. i just thought it didn't sound at all what i wanted to  do.

Comment: From the image, it looks like the conflict is between the react version required by the dependencies

Comment: Ya.. I did that and it still is having issues.. this time it says that it can't find the module "request".    I think the right way to do this it the first suggestion the error message makes which is "Fix the upstream dependency conflict".    How do i do that?

Comment: Yes, I agree.   so what are the steps to fix that?   i'm pretty new to this but i've learned a lot in the last day figuring out how to resolve other conflicts i had regarding rvm and rbenv which i switched to..  this is the furthest i have got with this .  I tried to get my. MacBook set up wit a dev environment like a year or so ago but had enough issues i put it off till trying it again now..  hoping this time with some fortitude i can make it happen.